# Azure Managed IDentity - On Prem Applications

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

1. We have several apps which are built using .NET are running in VMS(on-prem)
2. All apps will be registered to Azure AD.
3. Can we use user managed identity to access key vault form these on-prem apps

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 9):

No, you cannot use a Managed Identity from on-prem apps.

> [...] a managed identity is a service principal of a special type that may only be used with Azure resources.
>
> Source: [What are managed identities for Azure resources?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)

To see a list of resources currently supported, see [Services that support managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities).

You can, however, use a [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#service-principal-object) to connect to Key Vault from an application running on-premises.
To do so, [Use the portal to create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal).

For Service Principals, authentication can be done in two different ways: password-based authentication (application secret) and certificate-based authentication. Using a certificate is recommended, but you can also create an application secret.

> To access resources that are secured by an Azure AD tenant, the entity that requires access must be represented by a security principal. This requirement is true for both users (user principal) and applications (service principal). The security principal defines the access policy and permissions for the user/application in the Azure AD tenant. This enables core features such as authentication of the user/application during sign-in, and authorization during resource access.

> If you cannot use managed identity, you instead register the application with your Azure AD tenant, as described on [Quickstart: Register an application with the Azure identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app). Registration also creates a second application object that identifies the app across all tenants.

Comment: Rick : Thanks for the response
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview
says

You can use managed identities to authenticate to any resource that supports Azure Active Directory authentication including your own applications.

Comment: That's correct. This means you can use managed identity to have *your* Azure hosted application connect to Azure storage or to access *your* API, as long as it runs on Azure.